# Get property to array and write it to new array (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have code to get data from google api.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: dburl,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  type: 'GET',
  data: model,
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.length !== 0) {
      speeddata = data;
      for (var i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
        path = "path=" + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + ',' + speeddata[i].Longitude2;
        var googleurl = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?"
          + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
        $.ajax({
          url: googleurl,
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data) {
            speedlimits = data;
            console.log(speedlimits);
            for (var i = 0; i < speedlimits.length; i++) {
              speedobject.push({
                speedlimits: speedlimits[i].speedLimits.speedLimit
              });
            }
            console.log(speedobject);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("Error");
  }
});
```

Here is what I get in response here - `speedlimits`

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71trZ.png)

I try to take `speedLimit` property and push it to new object.

Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < speedlimits.length; i++) {
  speedobject.push({
    speedlimits: speedlimits[i].speedLimits.speedLimit
  });
}
```

But when I show speedobject in console it is empty.

Why so? Where is my problem?

Comment: The first problem in your code is `async: false`.

Comment: when you populate your object, you missplace i var, it's speedlimits.speedLimits[i].speedLimit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `speedlimits` object looks like this:

```
speedlimits = { // You're looping over this (speedlimits)
    speedLimits: [ // You should be looping over this (speedlimits.speedLimits[i])
        {speedLimit: 50},
        // ...
    ],
    snappedPoints: []
}
```

You are trying to loop over the `speedLimits` and `snappedPoints` items - not the elements within `speedLimits`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < speedlimits.speedLimits.length; i++) {
    speedobject.push({
        speedlimits: speedlimits.speedLimits[i].speedLimit
    });
}
```

Comment: Thsnk's for help

Answer (score 0):

according to the data example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits) the api returns an object, not an array.. so your success function would look like this.. Make sure you get the case right too.

```
success: function(data) {
  speedlimits = data.speedLimits;
  console.log(speedlimits);
  for (var i = 0; i < speedlimits.length; i++) {
    speedobject.push({
      speedlimits: speedlimits[i].speedLimit
    });

  }
  console.log(speedobject);
}
```